# Como definir o tamanho do arquivo numa resposta de Download?

Tags: c#, http, download

Tenho uma aplicação onde dou uma resposta com o download de um determinado arquivo no servidor para o cliente. Eu zipo os arquivos de imagens que estão numa pasta no servidor e dou uma resposta manipulando os headers para que o arquivo seja baixado.

Eu reparei que, quando esse arquivo gerado é um pouco maior, há uma demora para fazer o download do mesmo, porém não é exibido no navegador o tempo restante para download baseado no tamanho do arquivo.

Um exemplo escrito em Aspx WebForm:

```
string fullpath = GenerateZippedPhotos(id);

response.ContentType = "application/zip";

response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=remessa_fotos.zip");

response.WriteFile(fullpath);

response.Flush();
```

Para corrigir o problema descrito acima, o que é preciso fazer?

Existe alguma forma de  "falar para o navegador" o tamanho do arquivo que está sendo baixado?

Comment: **Não coloquei a tag [tag:csharp] porque não se trata de um problema específico da linguagem**

Comment: AddHeader( "Content-Length", tamanho )

Comment: Só isso já resolve?

Comment: Não consigo imaginar necessidade de mais que isso,

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acha mesmo que precisa da TAG C#? Por mim, pode colocar a vontade, eu só queria fazer uma pergunta no âmbito global :D

Comment: Se você zipar numa `stream` (sem nem precisar escrever no HD, apenas no socket), que é o jeito mais padrão de se enviar um zip arbitrário que não se deseja armazenar no servidor, você não tem como saber o tamanho a priori. Eu sofro isso com o Jenkins e com o Gitlab quando peço para baixar um diretório zippado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado verdade, ficando na memória, o que de qualquer forma já estava antes de gravar, se bem que desconheço o comportamento da plataforma .net (e c#), se o zip for grande não sei o quanto isto poderia ser custoso, talvez um envio de 256k e usar um flush, até mesmo um limitador de download, outra ideia seria um cache pro zip para evitar retrabalho, mas se eu entrar nisto as sugestões irão longe :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basicamente:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", "tamanho" );
```

Lembrando que o tamanho é em bytes, e só do corpo da requisição, sem os cabeçalhos. Normalmente as funções que lidam com o *filesystem* obtém isto com facilidade.

Em C# [(fonte)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380839/916193):

```
long tamanho = new System.IO.FileInfo("remessa_fotos.zip").Length;
```

Definição do W3:

> ### 14.13 Content-Length
>
> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET.
>
> ```
>    Content-Length    = "Content-Length" ":" 1*DIGIT
> ```
>
> An example is
>
> ```
>    Content-Length: 3495
> ```
>
> Applications SHOULD use this field to indicate the transfer-length of
>   the message-body, unless this is prohibited by the rules in section
>   4.4.

Que, resumindo é:

> O cabeçalho Content-Length indica o tamanho do corpo em octetos (unidades de 8 bits)  que serão enviados ao destinatário, ou que *seriam enviados* no GET no caso de consultas HEAD.
>
> As aplicações devem enviar este campo, a não ser que proibido pelas regras da seção 4.4

Mais em: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Nota: como mencionado pelo colega @Jefferson nos comentários, há situações em que não é desejável determinar de antemão o tamanho do arquivo. Um exemplo é justamente a geração de *streams* compactados, justamente para não precisar armazenar tudo em memória ou em disco antes de iniciar o envio. O *stream* pode ser gerado enquanto já é enviado, economizando memória e tempo.

Comment: Só que você precisa saber a priori o tamanho do arquivo... Se o @WallaceMaxters estiver fazendo direito (pelo visto não está), ele só mandaria o `stream` com a geração do ZIP, que só dá para saber o tamanho total da compactação **após** compactar tudo, não durante a compactação

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado neste caso ele teria que mandar chunked, mas ai já não daria para responder a pergunta, que é "como definir o tamanho" de forma a mostrar a barra de progresso (sem tamanho exato não dá, a não ser que ele estimasse para mais e fizesse um padding, o que provavelmente seria uma péssima idéia :)

Comment: Acho que posso fornecer uma resposta mais tarde... "em alguns casos não é possível/não é desejável"...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho válido, eu até pensei em falar no chunked, mas se estiver disposto a postar algo, prefiro. Acho relevante um complemento com a questão dos streams (principalmente dos gerados dinamicamente, que por sinal, acho subutilizados).

Comment: Do chuncked eu não domino, melhor não arriscar do que falar besteira. Mas da parte do "oh-oh" para zip em memória vou fazer

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado basicamente isso: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding - em vez de controlar o stream dando o tamanho final, vai se mandando bloco por bloco com apenas o tamanho de cada bloco já determinado, até que no final mande um "bloco vazio" para sinalizar o fim (e headers adicionais caso sejam relevantes).